# How do I test a scala ProcessBuilder with a URLBuilder?

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```scala
val url = new URL("https://example.com")
val tempDestination = Paths.get("/tmp/fred").toFile
for {
  _ <- Try(new URL(url) #> tempDestination !!)
  _ = streams.debug(s"Downloaded $url to $tempDestination with size equal to ${tempDestination.length} bytes")
  resource <- doStuff(tempDestination)
} yield resource
```

and somehow it seems to create issues upstream when the `url` points to a `404`.

How can I mock the HTTP call to `url` to validate behavior in a uTest?

Comment: My advice would be: wrap any abstraction you don't own in an abstraction you own and control. Then you have a control over how you test things, but also limit the damage when external SDK changes etc.

Comment: This is actually a very good suggestion, I was too much head down on this one. thanks!